# How to avoid Eclipse Xdebug Error "Illegal or not full path" window

Tags: eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I set up Eclipse to debug a PHP project (joomla) with XDebug.

The debuger works fine, however every time the execution stops in a break point, a "Problem Occured" window apears

Saying:

'Searching for local file ...' has encountered a problem.

An internal error occured during: "Searching for local file ...".

(on the Details)

An internal error occured durig: Seraching for local file...".
 Illegal or not full path:

The Debuger works, and it even opens the correct file to debug step-by-step. but this window comes again on every step.

How can it be configured to avoid this behavior?
Thankyou

I will/can post an img as soon as I am allowed to :-)

Comment: I see this when running with HHVM using xdebug.

Comment: I'm also running remote debugging over nginx and hhhv as fastcgi where the remote filesystem path doesn't map to my local file systesm.  I'm feeling this has something to do with the issue.  Going to dig in.

Answer (score 1):

I started running into this problem today, which is how I ran across this post. This appears to be related to breakpoints inside of `eval()`'d code. I would guess that XDebug is trying to find the name of the file from which the eval'd code is being run, to put it into the stacktrace. But it's failing because the eval'd code exists in memory, rather than on the filesystem.

I looked, but I couldn't find any way to make this stop happening. However, I did find an existing bug report for this problem on the Eclipse Bugzilla, [Bug 385559](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385559). The original poster found a barely acceptable workaround, which is probably why this simple bug hasn't been fixed in the year and a half since it was posted. If we both post our own experience with this bug to that page, maybe they'll be more likely to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For others having the same problem and looking into the bug discussion, the dirty warkaround mentioned by @CoreDumpError is to minimize the error window, as it is not modal: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385559#c2

In mac it's not possible to minimize the error window, but it's possible to place it anywhere on the screen.